# How to store exception to pseudo-variable?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How to store exception of the Function call in immediate window to pseudo-variable.

I have this code, where `Throw` throws an exception.

```cs
object x = Throw();
```

How to get an excepiton object and store it to pseudo-variable.

I tried to write `try/catch` but immediate window is not supported statements. And I tried to wrap it into lambda, but evaluation fails.

Comment: What is a ‘pseudo variable’?

Comment: @stuartd I think he means a variable that was defined in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Yes, @256Bits is right. This is a variable that was defined in the Immediate Window, not in the program being debugged.

Comment: Can it be stored in the monitoring window?

Answer (score 0):

You can see get the exception in Locals list or use `$exception` in Watch list, you should be able to capture the `var storedException = $exception` in the watchlist and use it in the immediate window

```
try
{
    // some code
}
catch (SomeException)
{ // place breakpoint at this line
}
```

You should be able to capture it like so just make sure you're at the proper breakpoint when doing it:

```
SomeException myException = $exception;
```

Comment: If function is evaluated in immediate window, `$exception` is not created.

Comment: store it in a variable in the watchlist first